# Access IMemoryCache service from AddHttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclienthandler

I am using .NET Core 3.1.

On Startup, I am adding the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<IApns, Apns>().ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };

        // How do I access memory cache (MyConfig expect it) - normally I use it injected. 
        var certificate = new MyConfig(...).GetCertificate 

        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        return handler;
    });
}
```

The problem is `MyConfig` is a class that expects `IMemoryCache`:

```
public MyConfig(IMemoryCache cache)
{
    _cache = cache;
}
```

The certificate is stored and loaded from memory cache.  How do I get around this please?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "get around this"? Get a valid `IMemoryCache` instance for loading the certificate?

Comment: Yeah, not sure how to "inject it" as normally it is injected when I use the class in the controller. In Startup, I am not so sure how. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new `IMemoryCache` object by using the `IServiceProvider` object which is passed through an overload of [`ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_HttpClientBuilderExtensions_ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IHttpClientBuilder_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider_System_Net_Http_HttpMessageHandler__):

```
services.AddHttpClient<IApns, Apns>().ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler((serviceProvider) =>
{
    var memoryCache = serviceProvider.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
    
    var certificate = new MyConfig(memoryCache).GetCertificate();
    // ...
}
```

If `MyConfig` is injected as a service, you can also load this one instead.